# How to get JobExecutionContext from a Partitioner

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I have a InitTasklet that runs before an Master/Slave with partitioner strategy. In this initial tasklet I access the database and get a list with ids and put into context:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution()
.getExecutionContext().put("listaBancos", lista);
```

I need to access this list in my Partitioner

I tried this way with no success: the method beforeJob is never executed.

```
public class BancoPartitioner extends JobExecutionListenerSupport ...

@Override
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    this.context = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    super.beforeJob(jobExecution);
```

}

I tried to autowired the stepExecution this way:
    @Value("#{stepExecution}")
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

but I get an exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'bancoPartitioner': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution .....stepExecution; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'stepExecution' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'.
```

Is there any way to access the Execution context from a Partitioner?

Comment: did you mark your bean with scope="step" to access late-binding?

Comment: For the Partitioner bean Spring tool only shows me these options for scope: prototype, request, session and singleton. When I force the step scope I get an exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.bancoPartitioner': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext

Comment: The beforeJob method for this listener will be executed before all the steps in the job (if wired correctly). The initTasklet which you are talking about would be a part of a step which will be executed after the beforeJob method has been called.

Can you provide your job.xml as that would clarify the flow of the job?

Comment: ow! now it works! I get the context this way:  @Value("#{stepExecution}")
 StepExecution context; thanks!

Comment: Saket: the beforeJob is executed after InitTasklet. The InitTasklet is the initial Step. The BancoPartitioner (which contains the BeforeJob) is the Partitioner for the second step of application. The before job doesn't work, but I get it using an autowired annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works with scope="step" in the declaration of Partitioner Bean, as bellabax explained.

Comment: can you post the full solution here?

Comment: I just put scope="step" in the bean definition.